# Импорт из excel в SQL

Tags: php, excel, sql

Ребят, всем привет.

Допустим, есть таблица в sql такого типа: id, date, time, title.
Создаю Excel файл с таким же заголовком и заполняем типичными данными.
Нашел уже библиотеку, и в принципе понятно, как реализовать, но есть один вопрос. Как быть с полем id? Сейчас по умолчанию в sql оно уникальное, и есть автоинкремент. Когда я буду добавлять данные, он мне не даст записать, т.к. поле уникальное, уберу уникальность, то где гарантия, что они будут уникальными? Не очень охота создавать таблицу в sql id, date, time, title. Надеюсь, вопрос понятен.

Comment: С чего Вы решили, что Id не даст записать? Автоинкремент срабатывает только, если Вы айди не пишите.

Comment: Уникальность и автоинкремент - вещи разные. Вы можете убрать автоинкремент, сохранив уникальность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы атрибут `AUTO_INCREMENT` срабатывал, достаточно не указывать столбец с данным атрибутом в запросе на вставку. С файлами импорта CSV аналогичная ситуация.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html